# Where can I find custom UITabBarSystemItem icons?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, icons, uitabbaritem

Is there a resource out there some place that has custom UITabBarSystemItem icons that others can use. I know you get some from Apple to start, but I would imagine there are a lot more that are very common. I don't see a reason for each person to recreate the wheel for things like home, settings, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [IconFinder](http://www.iconfinder.net). They have a very robust collection, and you can sort by image size. though these are not always perfect for the TabBar, you can find some good generic icons. You can also filter by license to find icons that are available for commercial use.

Comment: This is great. Thanks for the resource. Now, if I can only find a way to incorporate the skull and crossbones icon...

Answer (score 3):

Here is a list of some great resources I found. I have no connection with any of these sites just some resources I think are useful.

### Collections:

Free:

- [App bits](http://www.app-bits.com/free-icons.html)
- [The working group](http://blog.twg.ca/2009/09/free-iphone-toolbar-icons/)
- [Axialis Software](http://www.axialis.com/objects/ip_icon_09.shtml)

Free and paid:

- [Glyphish](http://glyphish.com/)
- [PixelPress](http://www.pixelpressicons.com/?p=108)
- [Tabs Icons](http://www.tabsicons.com/)

Paid:

- [Kombine](http://www.kombine.net/icon-store/iphone-tab-bar-icons)
- [eddit](http://www.eddit.com/shop/iphone_ui_icon_set/)
- [app-icons.com](http://app-icons.com/)
- [Icons Berlin](http://www.iconsberlin.com/)

---

### Create your own:

- [Icons Berlin Online Builder](http://www.iconsberlin.com/free-ipad-iphone-tab-bar-icon-editor.php)
- [speckyboy.com](http://speckyboy.com/2010/04/30/iphone-and-ipad-development-gui-kits-stencils-and-icons/)
- [Tutorial using Illustrator](http://devinsheaven.com/creating-uitabbar-uitoolbar-icons-in-adobe-illustrator/)
- [Tutorial using Omnigraffle](http://steveweller.com/articles/tabbar-icons/files/pixel-perfect-iphone-toolbar-and-tabbar-icons.php)
- [Tutorial using Photoshop](http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/How-to-create-iPhone-tab-bar-icons-properly/53608)

Answer (score 2):

You can get some free icons from [Glyphish](http://glyphish.com/) under the Creative Commons Attribution license.

Also, although it's not free there's a nice icon set available from [eddit](http://www.eddit.com/shop/iphone_ui_icon_set/). These work fine for TabBar items.

Comment: The Glyphish.com set is nice - and it's always cool to support 'open' works.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use following:

```
UITabBarItem *anItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemMore tag:0];
```

And the *system icons* are described and shown in:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html