# What are the available UITabBarController tab icons?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitabcontroller

How can i see all the icons available from the iOS SDK and how can i set them to my UITabBarController tabs ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There may be more, but you can check out the pulldown in Interface Builder for the Tab Bar Item's "Identifier" (in the Inspector view).

Update: The full list is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
typedef enum {
   UITabBarSystemItemMore,
   UITabBarSystemItemFavorites,
   UITabBarSystemItemFeatured,
   UITabBarSystemItemTopRated,
   UITabBarSystemItemRecents,
   UITabBarSystemItemContacts,
   UITabBarSystemItemHistory,
   UITabBarSystemItemBookmarks,
   UITabBarSystemItemSearch,
   UITabBarSystemItemDownloads,
   UITabBarSystemItemMostRecent,
   UITabBarSystemItemMostViewed,
} UITabBarSystemItem;
```

Looks like it is just the ones that Interface Builder shows.

If you are looking for custom icons, take a look at [this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554646/where-can-i-find-custom-uitabbarsystemitem-icons)